# How to make the width fit to the content when text wrapped?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind to create a card with an arrow. I want the arrow always next to the text 10px. But when the text is wrapped, the width of the text is larger than the actual width of the text.

[image]

I tried adding `width: fit-content` but the text will overflow and can't wrap. If I add `width: min-content` then the text always wraps.

I must use javascript to get the actually width of the text in this case, right?

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8 m-20 lg:max-w-[1200px]">
  <div class="w-full h-52 overflow-hidden shadow-xl p-8 flex items-center justify-start gap-4">
    <div class="min-w-[80px] min-h-[80px] bg-blue-500"></div>
    <p class="text-xl font-bold">Software Solutions</p>
    <svg width="7" height="12" viewBox="0 0 7 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M1.78125 0.75L6.25 5.5C6.375 5.65625 6.46875 5.84375 6.46875 6C6.46875 6.1875 6.375 6.375 6.25 6.53125L1.78125 11.2812C1.5 11.5938 1.03125 11.5938 0.71875 11.3125C0.40625 11.0312 0.40625 10.5625 0.6875 10.25L4.6875 6L0.6875 1.78125C0.40625 1.46875 0.40625 1 0.71875 0.71875C1.03125 0.4375 1.5 0.4375 1.78125 0.75Z" fill="#333940" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full h-52 overflow-hidden shadow-xl p-8 flex items-center justify-start gap-4">
    <div class="min-w-[80px] min-h-[80px] bg-blue-500"></div>
    <p class="text-xl font-bold pr-0 w-[fit-content]">Business process solutions</p>
    <svg width="7" height="12" viewBox="0 0 7 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M1.78125 0.75L6.25 5.5C6.375 5.65625 6.46875 5.84375 6.46875 6C6.46875 6.1875 6.375 6.375 6.25 6.53125L1.78125 11.2812C1.5 11.5938 1.03125 11.5938 0.71875 11.3125C0.40625 11.0312 0.40625 10.5625 0.6875 10.25L4.6875 6L0.6875 1.78125C0.40625 1.46875 0.40625 1 0.71875 0.71875C1.03125 0.4375 1.5 0.4375 1.78125 0.75Z" fill="#333940" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**

I don't think that this is possible with CSS alone.

See this answer for JS fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32222395/4536543

Here's my take on it:

```js
// get list of all spans
list = document.querySelectorAll('.content span');
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
  // retrieve width of span and apply it to parent
  w = list[i].offsetWidth;
  list[i].parentNode.style.width = w+1+"px"; // need to add 1 because sometimes width is not a whole number and Browser sometimes rounds it down which will trigger layout shift
}
```

```html
<div style="background: green; width: 134px; position: relative">
  <div class="content" style="background: yellow; float: left; max-width: 124px;">
    <span style="background: grey">
      somewhat long text goes here <!-- this is your "Business process solutions" -->
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="background: red; width: 10px; display: inline">
    >
  </div> <!-- this is your arrow -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I describe above, `min-content` make the text always wrap: here is my code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZgVEsnh4Hu

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. See update